# Debugging SystemJS module loading?

Tags: javascript, debugging, systemjs

I'm having an incredibly hard time understanding the modules and need a way to debug my issues.  Is there a way to enumerate modules and their exports using SystemJS?

The config file seems like a poorly documented minefield.  For modules that supply bundles like 'RxJs', if I include the bundle in a script tag or if I try to get it to load using the SystemJS config, how can I tell what I ***should*** be able to find in what I've loaded and where it is at?  For instance I can get `rxjs` to work by copying the `node_modules/rxjs` to `wwwroot/libs/rxjs' and using this:

```
System.config({
    map: {
        'rxjs': 'lib/rxjs'
    },
    packages: {
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }
```

This seems to load each individual file.  Now say I use a script tag to load the rxjs bundle.  How can I tell that the bundle has the modules I need?  Is there a way in SystemJS to see if it would use the bundle and what it could resolve to?

Comment: Funny, I found this because I am having trouble getting RxJS to load as well.

Comment: found this while trying to figure out why I get `GET http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I've written an explanation of the config file and how SystemJS uses it to determine where to find modules, after I also struggled to understand what it's doing and why I was getting 404 errors - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439855/what-does-systemjs-config-js-do-in-angular-2-packaging-structure/48780734#48780734

Answer (score 1):

`System.entries` Allows you to retrieve all modules in the System registry. Each value will be an array with two values: a key and the module.

```
for (const [id, ns] of System.entries()) {
      console.log(id); // 'http://localhost/path-to-file.js'
      console.log(ns); // { exportName: 'value' }
    };
```