# Pagination in Angular 2

Tags: angular, pagination

I am new to Angular 2 and I am trying to implement pagination in Angular 2. After a bit of research I found that the pagination logic need to be written in **systems.config.js**. My question is where can I find the file systems.config.js ? What is the need for the file ? If I need to create the file, the how will my application know how to invoke the file **systems.config.js**?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement some of the well known modules:

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/paginator
- http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/pagination

As for the `systems.config.js` that is only a file to configure new modules. 
You will need it if you want to use, above mentioned, modules.

About `systems.config.js`:

[What does systemjs.config.js do in angular 2 packaging structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439855/what-does-systemjs-config-js-do-in-angular-2-packaging-structure)